# Sharepoint online list in an MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to build an MVC ASP.NET appthat read in my sharepoint online a list
I included in MVC the Azure Active directory login, but I don't understand how to pass the credential to sharepoint site.
I use the Stefano's [tutorial](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Building-an-MVC-application-d71f26af) to build my app
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is single sign on if you are using azure active directory. you don't need to pass credentials